# Is it possible to put a row with specific data at row number one in SQL?

Tags: sql

Assume i have a table:

[image]

I want that row with `UserId ='ee'` always display at row number one every time i select this table in SQLQuery.

Is it possible?

Comment: Usually you would use an Order By clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
  from your_table
 order by UserId <> 'ee' -- "<>", because false < true
```

or (arguably clearer):

```
select *
  from your_table
 order by case when UserId = 'ee' then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: Double equal is a C language thing, not sure it will work in SQL

Comment: thanks @theMayer :) that always gets me (that, and writing "form" instead of "from", for some reason)

Comment: @giorgiga Thanks. I also research  more detail about ORDER BY. SELECT step produces a virtual table that includes also some "shadow" columns/expressions (all those that are in the ORDER BY clause but not in the SELECT list).  `order by case when UserId = 'ee' then 0 else 1 end` will put 0 into the shadow column of  UserId='ee' row others 1, and order select set by the shadow column.  We can also change value 0 to 'a' and 1 to 'b',then ORDER BY order select set depending on character priority. Hope this help some beginner like me.

Comment: Above concept i leaned from:[How does ORDER BY really work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38748/how-does-order-by-really-work)

Comment: This is also a solution. If one column of table contain more higher ordering priority value than others,  then you can do  `select * from your_table order by case when UserId = 'ee' then 'column1 name' else 'column2 name' end`,and this will put column1 value into shadow column of UserId='ee' row and column2 value to other rows. Make sure you know your column value very well, otherwise it will cause unimaginable ordering results.

Answer (score 2):

Use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY (case when UserId = 'ee' then 0 else 1 end) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CASE Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) or IF Clause to change to order.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM
Table
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN UserID = 'ee' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ASC, UserID ASC
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM 
Table
ORDER BY IIF(UserID = 'ee', 1, 2) ASC, UserID ASC
```

This way you give te ee value number 1 and all the others number 2 and order by those numbers. When those are ordered you order the duplicated 2's by the UserID itself.

Comment: Small nit, but I think a case clause has very slightly worse performance than a straight conditional. :)

Comment: Both of my examples run exactly as long as each other and get evaluated the same (select > sort > compute scalar > table scan). You got an example for me of what you mean with an straight condittional? Teach me :)

Comment: For a small table, the difference would not be detectable. We're talking optimization that would apply on the 1M+ row range.